# Prolog: using tell to create another .pl

Tags: prolog

So here is a method in my program where i want to write everything to the 'currentState.pl' however when i consult the file i get this error, line 27 is the tell() method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

.pl:27:24: Syntax error: Operator expected

```
saveState:-
             tell(‘currentState.pl’),
             listing(on),
             listing(left),
             listing(holding),
             told,
             write('Current State Saved'),nl.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be **tell('currentState.pl')**, instead of **tell(‘currentState.pl’)**, **'** instead of **‘** or **’**

Comment: @justin they appear when the code with quotes is copy/pasted from a web page sometimes. Not all posted code uses normal, ASCII single quotes.